# Should objects draw themselves? (Mixture of geometry and textures)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2

I am aware that similar questions have been asked many times before. However, this is a different case.

I am writing a game in C++ using SDL2. Currently, all objects draw themselves. They do this because they all draw slightly differently.

For instance, a Button contains a rectangle, drawn with `SDL_RenderFillRect();`

Buttons also contain text, which are drawn using `SDL_RenderCopy()`, which takes a texture generated by SDL_TTF as a parameter.

Additionally, a MapView widget (basically a grid that can load a tilemap) draws the grid out using a 'for' loop containing horizontal and vertical `SDL_RenderDrawLine()` calls.

Finally, the tiles themselves are stored as textures, drawn using `SDL_RenderCopy()`.

I understand that it is generally preferable to NOT have objects draw themselves. However, because there is so much variation in how the objects are drawn, I'm not sure of another way!

I thought it might be possible to have a GetTexture() function for each object, and the ones using textures could simply 'return texture', while the geometric objects could generate a texture. This gets complicated with my MapView object, because the grid is constantly updated when the user navigates around the game world (an offset value is changed and the grid is redrawn when moved).

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with objects drawing themselves. Usually you would have a render queue so you get to control whats drawn and do other things like culling out objects, etc. It make no difference whether the objects draw themselves or you draw all of them with one function which accesses data from each object. You could have a set of draw functions one for each type of object and switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

Like so many questions of this type the answer is: it depends on your program.

If you are only every going to draw it the same way using SDL, then no reason why not. Another alternative might be to have a specific rendering class for each object, but that's doubling the effort. Having all your rendering code in a single class or function works fine too, but it gets big and complicated fast.

It's a judgement call based on the complexity of your code and what you want to do with it in the future, and my advice is to choose the simplest solution. As long as you've considered the potential downsides, you can make an educated decision.